# How to calculate and store in DB some field values on Model save hook?

Tags: atk4, php

What I want to accomplish is the following.

I need to save in database some field which value should be automatically calculated using other values in its Model (or related models). I guess I should do this using one of these model hooks - beforeInsert, beforeModify, afterInsert, afterModify, but how exactly I should do this?
Also, this field should be not changeable, but visible in UI forms/grids.

For example,

```
class Model_Address extends Model_Table{
  public $table='address';
  function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->hasOne('Territory');
    $this->addField('street');
    $this->addField('house');
    $this->addField('number');
    $this->addField('name')->readonly(true); // this should be calculated on save

    $this->addHook('beforeModify',$this);
  }

  // How to write this to set name=street+house+number+territory.name ???
  function beforeModify($m){
    $ter_name = $m->ref('Territory')->get('name');
    $m['name'] = $m['street'].' '.$m['house'].' '.$m['number'].', '.$ter_name;
    return $m;
  }
}
```

---

Edit:

Will this solution will be correct? It looks that it's working, but I'm not sure yet.

```
class Model_Address extends Model_Table{
  public $table='address';
  function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->hasOne('Territory');
    $this->addField('street');
    $this->addField('house');
    $this->addField('number');
    $this->addField('name')->readonly(true); // this should be calculated on save

    $this->addHook('beforeSave',$this);
  }

  function beforeSave($m){
    $t=$m->ref('territory_id');
    if($t->loaded()){
      $m=set('name',$m->get('street').' '.$m->get('house').' '.$m->get('number').', '.$t->get('name'));
    }
    return $this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. Also this could have been inside "afterLoad" hook.

Comment: btw - you should add answer to your own question and then select your answer. Helps other to see it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a correct solution. At least one of them :)

```
class Model_Address extends Model_Table{
  public $table='address';
  function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->hasOne('Territory');
    $this->addField('street');
    $this->addField('house');
    $this->addField('number');
    $this->addField('name')->readonly(true); // this should be calculated on save

    $this->addHook('beforeSave',$this);
  }

  function beforeSave($m){
    $t=$m->ref('territory_id');
    if($t->loaded()){
      $m=set('name',$m->get('street').' '.$m->get('house').' '.$m->get('number').', '.$t->get('name'));
    }
    return $this;
  }
}
```

I could use afterLoad hook too, but I have decided to better save this concatenated value in database to minimize load time calculations.

Also when you use afterLoad hook you should be aware that it uses lazy load. That is, it loads only these model fields which are asked and not all of them.

For example, if you have grid with only columns street, house and name, then afterLoad will load only these three fields. Flat, territory_id and number will be empty no matter what. So desired functionality will not fully work that way.
Same applies to using addExpression + callback field.

Answer (score 0):

in the previous version (4.1) the hooks are already in the framework and the functions just do nothing when called unles you override them in the model.

i assume this is the same in 4.2 that the beforeModify, beforeInsert and beforeDelete just need defining in the model and add whatever logic you need in there - this includes adding other models that might have calculated fields or php to do some calcs and dsql statements to populate.